# Uniform convergence and Schwartz space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, uniform-convergence, schwartz-space

Consider a function $f \in S(\mathbb{R})$ in the Schwartz space and define the sequence of functions $(f_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ by $f_n(x): = f(\frac{x}{n})$. I would like to show that $f_n$ does not converge uniformly toward $0$ as $n \to \infty$.
(It was true with $x \mapsto \frac{x}{n} \cdot f(\frac{x}{n})$).

In order to do that, I supposed that the convergence is uniformly and I tried to find a contradiction with the convergence of the integrals, but without success.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Been too long, I forget Schwartz space, but just glancing at your question, wouldn't it be converging to $f(0)$, not $0$?

Comment: @Alan using the definition of the Schwarz space, we can prove that in fact we have the pointwise convergence to 0. Indeed, if $f$ is in the Schwartz space, then in particular $\lim_{|x| \to \infty} |f(x)| = 0$. (If I’m not wrong)

Comment: But here your values of the input of $f(x)$ aren't tending to infinity, they are going to 0, as what is going to infinity is $n$, and you are inputting $\frac x n$

Comment: @Alan what I stupid error I did, sorry yes of course you’re right!

Comment: Happens to the best of us, glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 2):

You have $\|f_n\|_\infty = \|f\|_\infty$, so you have uniform convergence to zero if and only if $f \equiv 0$.